# Help users create dummy links that are not to unrelated commercial sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks, warning

A search for domains like mysite.com provides thousands of results on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and hundreds on [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com). I sampled some. Each and every one I checked was a post by someone ignorant about http://example.com, http://example.org and [.example TLD](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606#page-2), as defined in [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606). Other "natural examples" domains are abused pretty much too.

My request is - disallow these:

- mysite.*TLD*
- site.*TLD*
- abc.*TLD*
- xyz.*TLD*
- *[one letter repeated].TLD*

When they are detected, propose http://example.com or http://example.org. With old questions, use robot or find other way to edit them.

---

Even if SEO is not a problem, professional sites about Internet and associated technologies should not ignore RFC on such a large scale. Not to mention linking porn like about thousand links to xxx.com - I was already detected as one who visits "sites related to content forbidden here" by a firewall or two thanks to that.

I can assure you: you don't want to explain to your boss why are you searching for "adult content" in working hours, or agrotourism farm owner why that happens under his roof. Even WSODs are not nice. Now I think I have SE whitelisted, but anyway... Sadly, firewall was right, I did have xxx.com mentioned in my search results here and on Drupal Answers.

Comment: Would programmatic links to images posted on SO, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10862262/230513), be OK?

Comment: @trashgod - links to images and links to related sites should be OK. Problem is with domains that belong to commercial entities and have nothing to do with the question. Especially ones that seems to take short, "natural" name on purpose, as only these are misused in significant amount to care. Also, now all images seems to be served from imgur.com anyway and in no way I'm proposing to disallow imgurl. It's related as it hosts material used in question, so it deserves each and every SEO benefit it may have from that.

Comment: I would also suggest to disallow `xxx.com`. I've had an [unpleasant experience](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17104358/putting-a-new-line-in-the-code-below/17104547#comment24745576_17104547).

Comment: @HamZa updated, in a more general way. Good for you?

Comment: While I think it's a good idea to get people to use the domains specifically set up to be used as examples and not inadvertently drive up the Google Juice of actual sites, I don't see how this will be possible in an automated way. There's just too much chance that something will be changed that shouldn't. Sentient intervention is required. This is probably better off as a clean-up project by a team of volunteers.

Comment: I'm not clear on what the problem is here.  You're saying that someone might accidentally arrive on Stack Overflow because they googled for mysite.com?  How is that hurting the world?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm saying someone may go to xxx.com from a Stack page. Pretty embarrassing at work. See HamZa's comment. And I'm saying Stack gives traffic and reputation (not mechanical one, just human) to sites people don't even know they are mentioning - on Drupal Answers mysite.com happens to be mentioned as a dummy link also in questions that touches hosting problems - giving them unintentional credit. Last but not least, professional page breaking RFC thousands of times does not look professional.

Comment: @HamZa seems you told me why I experience WSODs. Thank you... I guess ;) (question updated)

Comment: Slightly off-topic question: are there any well-known example domains that have MX records?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

The "adult content" rationale is pretty compelling here. I've blacklisted the following URLs:

- http://mysite.com
- http://site.com
- http://abc.com
- http://xyz.com
- http://xxx.com
- http://foo.com
- http://domain.com
- http://mydomain.com

...along with variations that include the "www." subdomain, and the .org and .net TLDs.

This doesn't remove existing examples from the site, but will require that they be changed if the post is edited - and will block all new instances from being added. Folks trying to edit any post containing these will now see:

[image: Body cannot contain ... Please use example.com (or .org or .net) for fake URLs.]

Which links to this page: [Why are certain example URLs like http://site.com/ and http://mysite.com/ blocked from post content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke)

**January 9, 2015:** this blacklist is now live on all sites EXCEPT for meta.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There is a domain which is chosen as a standard example name... example.com (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com). Maybe we could mention it in a help page?

Comment: I figured we'd mention it the first time someone asked about the error here on meta, @Sklivvz. If we can get a hook for a help-link into the blacklist though, it'd be worth writing up something for that.

Comment: Thank you, gentleman. @Sklivvz I think pretty good explanation of http://example.com/ is directly on http://example.com/ ;) Simple, direct, and surely comes from authorized source. But link to Wikipedia might work, too. Depends of the detail level you want to give your users.

Comment: Is it implemented on Drupal Answers? And what about [using it in code blocks](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/revisions/96719/1)?

Comment: Unfortunately without some specific text that says "use example.com" this solution is just confusing. It just tells you that you cant add http in your answer. It look several attempts and a post on meta before I found this info.

Comment: We currently have someone going on a suggested edit spree trying to change all the "site.com"s to "example.com"s. Should we approve them?

Comment: @Undo I decided to go ahead and focus the edits on hunting down instances of `xxx.com` I see

Comment: @jdp Yeah, that's much better. I would strongly suggest, though, editing *something* else in the post to be better - many will reject otherwise.

Comment: @Shog9, please have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226793/should-we-approve-edits-that-just-change-commercial-links-to-example-com/226832#226832 and let us know what your views are

Comment: Please bring this to SF. And soon.

Comment: Done. @Michael. If you need the pattern extended, post a request on meta.sf

Comment: @Shog9 Any chance we can get it on Drupal Answers too? http://meta.drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3048/can-we-have-porn-link-prevention-implemented-here

Comment: Not letting users cite ABC.com is likely to hurt on [Movies & TV](https://movies.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: [Doesn't look like it](http://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Aabc.com), @tepples. The network site - [abc.go.com](http://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Aabc.go.com) - isn't blacklisted.

Comment: Can we just drop the `http://` part of this? I commonly see people trying to get around this restriction by dropping `http://` and using only the domain, rather than using example.com.

Comment: if they drop the http:// part, then it won't be automatically converted to a link, @Michael - which was the problem we set out to solve here. I should take https links into account though - done.

Comment: Trying to edit [Why are certain example URLs like http://site.*/ and http://mysite.*/ blocked from post content?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208963) makes the alert appear (I couldn't post this comment either). Isn't this disabled in MSE?

Comment: Try it now, @braiam

Comment: It allowed me. Lets see comments http://site.com. If you can read it....

Comment: I think http://domain.com should also be blacklisted.

Comment: That's a good idea, @Donald. Done.

Comment: ...I just came uncomfortably close to clicking `xxx.com` while at work

Comment: I think any repetition of a single letter should be blocked. **Especially X**.

Comment: Domain.com is a valid domain hosting company; if I want to recommend it to someone, how can I?

Comment: "this blacklist is now live on all sites EXCEPT for meta.stackexchange.com" - Not sure if this has _recently_ changed, but this "blacklist" does _not_ appear to be on "all sites"? Or even all "programming" sites where example domains are often used!? A few main sites where I think this should be added, but currently does not appear to, include: "Software Engineering", "Ask Ubuntu", "Code Review" and "Joomla". (?)

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog You can still reference `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` - it only seems to _trip the sensor_ when entering a full/absolute URL with "http(s)" protocol  eg. `http://domain.com` etc. - so you can't link to it.

Comment: This JSON is blocked from use since it contains the actual abc.com: `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=friends`

Answer (score 9):

Any links that are actually created accidently like http://mysite.com include a `nofollow`, so I don't think there are any SEO benefits for those domains anyhow. The only possible problem is someone clicking on said link thinking it goes somewhere useful, but that sounds like an unlikely and insignificant problem to me.

The nofollow is removed if [the post is considered reputable enough](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111279/remove-nofollow-on-links-deemed-reputable), so if there truly are a number of "reputable"  posts linking to mysite and whatnot, it may warrant a modification of the `nofollow` removal logic to skip those links.

Comment: Mołot, although that report indicates that the nofollow attribute might not prevent search engines from indexing a mentioned address, indexing is not Stack Exchange's concern. Stack Exchange has no interest in concealing the *existence* of the linked page. Rather, the attribute is applied to avoid influencing the *ranking* of the linked page by having Stack Exchange's link be interpreted as some sort of endorsement.

Comment: @RobKennedy OK, even if I'll accept everything you say my non-SEO arguments still apply - porn links like xxx.com and human reputation given to sites authors did not meant to mention are bad. Breaking RFC on page that claims is for pros is not good. So let's say for now I accept your explanation and my request is due to all other reasons provided, OK?