# Let's edit to remove "please upvote" and "please accept"

Tags: discussion, edits

Today I decided to do [a search on "please up vote,"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please+up+vote%22) and it got 31 results. I thought, that's not bad, so I reduced it to 8 by editing.

Well, that felt pretty good, until I did a few more searches. Here's what I found:

- ["please mark my answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please+mark+my+answer%22) - 24 results (this one's pretty much guaranteed no false positives)
- ["please vote up"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please+vote+up%22) - 96 results
- ["please upvote"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%22please+upvote%22) - 199 results :(
- ["please accept"](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22please+accept%22) - **523 results** (!!!)

Could I get a little community help with this? Please help edit this uselessness out of posts. **BUT**, remember to fix everything else in the post as well! (And if you can only suggest edits, it would probably be better to let 2k-ers do it so that you don't flood the queue `;)`)

Comment: The "fix everything else in the post as well" is the tricky part... but agree this should be done!

Comment: _"it would probably be better to let 2k-ers do it so that you don't flood the queue ;))"_ But flooding queues is fun! Until I start reviewing the queue, that is...

Comment: Please accept my apology, but I'm sorry I don't have time for this.  Does that make it 524?  :o)

Comment: It would probably be better that not everyone do it at one time at well so we don't kill the front page with these posts.

Comment: +1 SO has one less messed up answer :)

Comment: Should we still remove if the post is old and doesn't have anything else to correct?

Comment: @psubsee2003 [that shouldn't be a problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207144/shouldnt-we-be-cleaning-up-these-porn-links#comment659319_207144)

Comment: @Stijn good to know.

Comment: I've noticed that for "please upvote", a fair portion of the answers reference an answer on another question and say "please upvote the answer I have referenced" - which I don't mind, but what's everyone else's opinion?

Comment: @OGHaza it's less of an issue than "please vote for me", but it is still meta commentary that shouldn't be in answers.

Comment: @ogh does it make any contribution to actually answering the question? No: it should go then.

Comment: @rene, nice, I did about 30 "please upvote"/"please upvote this"/"upvote this answer" ones

Comment: Related: *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)*