# How to handle answers that ask to check as correct if they helped?

Tags: discussion, answers

I came accross some answers lately that closed with the request to mark it as correct if it helped solving the problem.

I felt this kind of request should not be included in an answer and does not help at all especially if the answer is short and posted quickly after the question was asked.

How to handle such answers? Ignore? Edit?

Comment: we edit them out in a community effort started here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/220539/please-upvote-and-accept-this-question

Comment: that is what i was looking for. did not find the discussion though. thanks

Comment: Please accept my comment as correct and upvote and award bounties (and maybe visit some of my other valuable answers and questions in the next few days and upvote those as well, but take it easy otherwise the serial upvote will be reversed) :-)

Comment: @rene you forgot bounty ;)

Answer (score 5):

Edit them out, same as you would for "thanks", [signatures/taglines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5029/162102), etc.  If the user is new, try to leave an explanatory edit message and/or comment.

Comment: If the user is new it is unlikely (though of course not impossible) that he would know enough to ask for an answer acceptance.

Comment: @Alex fair point.