# Why are certain example URLs like https://site.com/ and https://mysite.com/ blocked from post content?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, faq-proposed, blocklist

Why is https://site.com/ and https://mysite.com/ blocked from the post content on the main site?

I tried to make a sample URL and I had to use https://testsite.com instead.

Comment: Related: [Help users create dummy links that are not to unrelated commercial sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186529/help-users-create-dummy-links-that-are-not-to-unrelated-commercial-sites)

Comment: Search engine fodder (transcribed message when attempting to submit an edit containing `https://mysite.com`): *"Body cannot contain `"https://mysite.com"`. Please use example.com (or .org or .net) for fake URLs. [More info](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke)"*

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Use the URLs that are reserved for this purpose: [example.com](https://example.com), [example.net](https://example.net), [example.org](https://example.org). See: [Wikipedia's article "*Example.com*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com).

[site.com](https://site.com) and [mysite.com](https://mysite.com) are blacklisted network-wide. These sites appear to be created for the express purpose of driving traffic to those sites from folks who want to use them as example URLs.

[abc.com](https://abc.com) is also blacklisted. If you want to refer to the American Broadcasting Company's website, use [abc.go.com](https://abc.go.com).

For details, see: [Help users create dummy links that are not to unrelated commercial sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186529/help-users-create-dummy-links-that-are-not-to-unrelated-commercial-sites/207155#207155)

Comment: maybe an improvement is to add that as an alternative. "http://site.com is blocked. try using http://example.com instead."

Comment: @DanielA.White Or replace instances of that with example.com.

Comment: @RobertHarvey what about having an official meta page that is linked to?

Comment: It's merely two of several blacklisted terms.

Comment: @RobertHarvey  the biggest problem with the way it is, it doesn't explain why.

Comment: Well, now we have one.

Comment: @RobertHarvey FAQ time?

Comment: Please note that http://example.com, http://example.net and  http://example.org are also self-explanatory and points to http://www.iana.org/ - pretty much the highest authority in the matters of domain names :)

Comment: It's ironical, you drive traffic to those sites writing how bad they are driving traffic from some folks ;)

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think Daniel was just asking that the message saying that it's blocked also suggests http://example.com (which shouldn't be hard to do).

Comment: @Dukeling: The blacklisting system accepts a list of regexes that identify the blacklisted terms.  Calling out one of those terms specifically would require modifying the blacklisting system itself; you can't just stick a custom error message in there for one particular term.

Comment: @RobertHarvey My guess is that URLs are a big enough thing such that it can be treated separately (but it's a guess, since I don't have access to that data). Won't it be simple enough to simply make two calls to the blacklisting system (or however it works) with 2 regexes displaying different messages (one for URLs and one for the others)? To figure out the right URL to replace your blocked URL with can involve a bit of effort (and possibly a few Meta questions for those who didn't extensively search first, which need to be answered).

Comment: Or, y'know, you can do what the error message implies, and simply try something else.

Comment: Sure, anyone should be able to find a domain that works, but it would be better to have them use the *correct* domain (if for no other reason that to prevent the work caused by answering Meta questions about it, blacklisting new domains and changing the domains in questions). So it may not be worth the dev time or additional overhead, but it's worth a consideration.

Comment: And why is that a problem? No one is forced to click a link. I just entered abc.com which also was blocked and I am pretty sure ABC didn't register that site to receive illegitimate traffic.

I don't like all these "protect the users from themselves" attitude and rules on stackexchange.com. We need more darwinism on internet.

Comment: @user23122 An edit to address the ABC issue is in the suggestion queue.

Comment: It's a little silly that one cannot link to eg https://www.domain.com/help/article/domain-management-how-to-update-nameservers

Comment: @d-b the problem is not just that. The fact that so many names/TLDs were used in some documentation and hence misused everywhere is EXACTLY the reason why `.mail` or `.home` TLD can not exist today, because they were abused. See ICANN documentation about the new round of gTLDs starting in 2012. You can agree or not these TLDs would be useful, that is besides the point. They should not be forbidden to exist just because they were abused by some many wrong documentation.

Comment: "blacklisted network-wide" - This "blacklisting" does _not_ appear to be "network-wide". In fact, there are a numbering of "programming" sites where I think this should be "blacklisted", but currently is not. eg. "Software Engineering", "Ask Ubuntu", "Code Review", "Joomla" (there may be others). (?)

Comment: I get that you block them when posted as actual links. But why do you have to disallowed them also when they are inside a block of code?

Comment: I get `https://abc.com` returned in this link and cannot use it in an example `https://api.tvmaze.com/search/shows?q=friends`