# Bias against the Australian Broadcasting Corporation

Tags: bug, status-completed, hyperlinks, internationalization

On Skeptics Stack Exchange, I tried posting a link to http://www.abc.net.au/news/2014-12-12/raw-milk-mountain-view-farm-asked-to-recall-products/5963614 in a comment

And got an error message and referred to [Why are certain example URLs like http://site.com/ and http://mysite.com/ blocked from post content?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke)

Do what you want with abc.com, but leave abc.net.au alone!

Comment: All hail the ABC!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I was lazy and didn't bother trying to detect the end of the domain. And I'd have gotten away with it too, if not for you meddling foreigners and your crazy domain names!

Fixed. Block now matches abc.com but not abc.com.net.org.au or abc.com-score.cc.

Answer (score 27):

The following regular expression is the culprit:

```
https?://(www\.)?(xxx|xyz|abc|site|mysite|mydomain)\.(com|org|net)
```

It looks like this one could hit a few valid sites. This also looks like a blacklist that shouldn't even be active on Skeptics, as it would only be useful on SO and similar sites.

To actually remove or edit the expression we need an SE employee.

Comment: Well, the whole point of it is to "hit" valid sites: it assumes that the sites with this address are valid and thus have no place in code examples. Of course, I agree with you that this functionality is probably not needed on network sites which are unlikely to contain code examples.

Comment: This has nothing to do with *code* examples, @rumtscho - folks repeatedly used these domains in *example URLs*. And I'm not going to try to keep a list of sites where this hasn't been a problem yet; if it's breaking one site, best fix it everywhere.