# Bad URL check performed on edit, but not on initial question submission?

Tags: bug, edits

I am not sure if this is a bug or a design error, but I came across this issue on SE Information Security. I assume that the same code is employed across the various SE sites, so I am posting my question here.

I was trying to edit the question, [trackback spotted in multple http errors](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/57872/trackback-spotted-in-multple-http-errors), when I noticed that I could not submit the edit, due to a URL containing `mydomain.net`, which I had not added.

[image: Submission Error]

However, the question was obviously asked and entered with this URL in the body text, so was the same URL check not performed when the question was initially submitted? Here is the question containing the erroneous URL

[image: Question containing bad URL]

Comment: The abswercis simple... The check did not exist when asked. That is a relatively new check.

Comment: OK, thanks. However, that now means that the question is not able to be edited... _unless_ one changes the URL as well, I guess.

Comment: Correct. The same issue plagues other blacklisted items (for example "problem" it's not allowed in titles but used to be allowed so when editing you have to fix it before submitting.

Comment: Also related: [Why are certain example URLs like http://site.com/ and http://mysite.com/ blocked from post content](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke)