# Cannot edit title of the question if the body is defective

Tags: bug, edits, hyperlinks, title

I tried editing the title of [nginx rewite for new links structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759012/nginx-rewite-for-new-links-structure), but was precluded by doing so.

The following was the error message:

> ×
>   Body cannot contain "http://www.domain.com".
>
> Please use example.com (or .org or .net) for fake URLs. More info
>
> http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963/why-are-certain-example-urls-like-http-site-com-and-http-mysite-com-blocke

This seems like a wrong kind of UX -- if you didn't add any invalid domains, and didn't even touch question body, why should you be precluded from fixing the title?

(In the above question, the change may be trivial, but I don't want to assume the responsibility for editing a body of a really poorly-written question, as that's a sure rabbit hole.)

Comment: But you can still edit the question title

Comment: @AnthonyPham how?

Comment: @AnthonyPham No, you can't. See my answer.

Comment: @iBug So the OP means edit in means of saving the edit? You can edit the title but you sure can't save the edit...

Comment: @AnthonyPham ...Who edits a post without saving it?

Answer (score 1):

From [*Shog9*'s answer](/a/207155/350567),

> This doesn't remove existing examples from the site, but **will require that they be changed if the post is edited** - and will block all new instances from being added. Folks trying to edit any post containing these will now see:

So it's not a bug. It's intended to be like so. You have to remove invalid links whenever you attempt to edit a post, even if you're leaving body intact.

Comment: All those other answers are dated several years ago, yet the question I'm trying to edit is only a few months old — how exactly is that not a bug and/or a new issue?

Comment: @cnst A small guess: The blacklist is still growing and, at the time of that post, www.domain.com isn't in the backlist.