# Change links in errors and warnings to HTTPS

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, ssl, warning, blocklist

Another [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298987/323179) here on Meta brought something to my attention. Most links in errors and warnings that come up when posting or editing still are HTTP. I have a few examples listed below from various sites. I think this will need a dev to fix.

---

Trying to use (or edit a post with) a link shortener on Stack Overflow:

> Body cannot contain "[blacklisted link]".
>
> Please avoid using URL shorteners; they can break without leaving any useful artifact and are often used to obscure spam or malicious links.
> Editors: please replace the short URL noted above with the URL it redirects to!
> For details, see [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts).

Link is `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313621/blacklist-the-use-of-common-link-shorteners-in-posts`

---

Using the [virtualbox] tag on Server Fault (see [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/8523/356904)):

> Questions about personal and development use of VirtualBox are off-topic at Server Fault. You may be able to get help at [Super User](http://superuser.com/tags/virtualbox/info).

Link is `http://superuser.com/tags/virtualbox/info`

---

Using the [identification-request] tag on Anime & Manga (see [here](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2817)):

> The 'identification-request' tag is not allowed.
>
> The Identification Request tag is deprecated and now off-topic, see [our discussion](http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions) on the topic. Existing questions are currently in the process of removal.

Link is `http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/2805/what-wed-like-to-do-about-those-gosh-darn-identification-requests-questions`