# Wrong URL leaked through blacklist?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, domain-names, blocklist

In [this question](/q/298987), *cnst* tried to edit [a question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41759012/nginx-rewite-for-new-links-structure) and was responded with

> × Body cannot contain "http://www.domain.com".
>
> Please use example.com (or .org or .net) for fake URLs. More info:
>   http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208963

I posted [an answer](/a/298991) quoting [*Shog9*'s answer](/a/207155).

The reason is simple: Blacklisted domains should not be posted, and should not pass when edited. **But how was it posted?** The SO question was [asked on **Jan 20, 2017**](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41759012/revisions), but *Shog9*'s answer was [posted in **November 2013**](/posts/207155/revisions). Had the blacklist failed for as long as 3 years or what else happened?

Comment: I'm not sure what you ask here. This filter does not exist in MSE as Shog says himself: "January 9, 2015: this blacklist is now live on all sites EXCEPT for meta.stackexchange.com"

Comment: @ShadowWizard How was that question *posted* on SO?

Comment: oh, I see. Interesting indeed!

Comment: Actually, the block started at May 6th, 2014 but still, years before that SO question was posted

Answer (score 3):

The only explanation I can think of, is that the list has been updated somewhere between January 2017 when that question was posted and yesterday when someone tried to edit it and got the error.

As [this comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269625/does-the-xxx-com-blacklist-not-apply-to-question-titles#comment83936_269625) from August 2014 proves, domain.com was **not originally blocked**:

> It's not that it doesn't match the title, it's that the URL is only blocked if it is preceded by an `http://` (which would make it clickable in a post body). This is the actual blacklist currently being used: **`http://(www\.)?(xxx|xyz|abc|site|mysite|mydomain)\.(com|org|‌​net)`**

Comment: That's what I commented under my answer: `@cnst A small guess: The blacklist is still growing and, at the time of that post, www.domain.com isn't in the backlist.`

Comment: @iBug yup, well, let's wait for some official confirmation... :)