# Why can't I add an example http url in an answer?

Tags: support, answers, markdown, hyperlinks

I tried to answer someone's question about a URL format with an example:

```
http://mysite.com/service.asmx?blah=something
```

I got an error saying I can't save an answer with `http` in it. How can I get around this?

Here is the question: [@requestmapping feature in pure asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22494779/requestmapping-feature-in-pure-asp-net)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`example.com`](http://example.com) as the domain for sample URLs:

```
http://example.com/service.asmx?blah=something
```

to mark them as sample text instead of a 'live' URL (which yours is not). `mysite.com` is an *actual domain*, and you should not use it even in sample URLs. The domain is [explicitly blocked on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186529/help-users-create-dummy-links-that-are-not-to-unrelated-commercial-sites).

`example.com` (or the [`.org`](http://example.com), [`.net`](http://example.net) or [`.edu`](http://example.edu) variants) on the other hand, is [specifically reserved](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com) (by [RFC 2606](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2606)) for this very purpose.

Comment: You learn a new thing every day :)

Comment: But oddly I can ask a question with it in (see above).

Comment: The site name is not blocked here as that would make it needlessly hard to ask questions about the block.