# What URL should be used for example websites?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I have a question involving a program which includes links to `www.PrivateCorprateWebsite.com`.

Before posting my code, I would like to replace these URLs with something more generic. I've seen a few different example domains, including `abc.com`, `example.com`, `fakewebsite.com`, etc. Some of these redirect to real sites, while others give *'page not found'* errors.

**Is there an official stance on which dummy URL I should use when referring to unrelated commercially owned websites?**

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186529/help-users-create-dummy-links-that-are-not-to-unrelated-commercial-sites

Answer (score 9, accepted):

example.com, example.net, and example.org (amongst others) are domains specifically created and [reserved by IANA](https://www.iana.org/domains/reserved) for...examples.

> These domains may be used as illustrative examples in documents without prior coordination with us. They are not available for registration or transfer.

Use those.