# Can domain.com be added to the example domain blacklist?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, blocklist, domain-names

Several popular example domains such as `site.com`, `mydomain.com`, and `mysite.com` are [now disallowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103550/should-we-enforce-use-of-iana-example-domains) in the body of questions and answers.

[image]

Can `domain.com` be added to this blacklist?   It is the the most popular of [the inappropriately used example domains on the webmasters website](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1222/example-domain-cleanup). Here is the top of the list I pulled together of what people were using as example domains besides `example.com` on webmasters.  Three of the top four are now disallowed, but not the most popular.

```
1772 - domain.com
1392 - mysite.com -- DISALLOWED
1091 - mydomain.com -- DISALLOWED
510 - site.com -- DISALLOWED
293 - website.com
256 - yourdomain.com
209 - mywebsite.com
186 - yoursite.com
122 - domain.tld
69 - sitename.com
64 - mycompany.com
61 - newdomain.com
```

It might also be nice to go a little deeper and add  `website.com`, `yourdomain.com`, `mywebsite.com`, and `yoursite.com` to the blacklist as well.  After that, there seems to be a cutoff in usage that would make it a reasonable place to stop.

Comment: Those 3 disallowed sites are actually web hosting companies. They can be useful for webmasters. What's the point of disallowing them?

Comment: @narawagames They shouldn't be used in examples, http://example.com is there for that purpose. Besides, site.com isn't a web hosting site, it's a redirecting site to something completely different, probably only to make more people visit the site.

Comment: Regarding your test, the blacklist isn't active here on MSE.

Comment: Yes, I found that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has been implemented at some point, silently:

> [image]

Comment: I think you should be awarded a badge "Precision Shovel"